# How to recover deleted WSUS Administration from IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, iis-8.5

The default WSUS Administration somehow got deleted from IIS Sites by doing-> Right Click -> "remove" under  - Sites

I now need to recover the site, preferably without configuring WSUS from scratch. Any idea if I can simply recover a site? Is there such a feature of "accidental deletion" section as in Active Directory?

Comment: The quickest answer is to remove WSUS, reboot, then add it back again. There used be an option to save the settings/database when uninstalling WSUS, so when you reinstall, everything will still be there. Unfortunately, I am not positive that option is still available in the version on Win2012 R2.

Comment: Configuration history might save you here http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/using-configuration-history-with-iis-7-and-iis-8#Restoring